# Htaccess Using RewriteMap with a text file

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't use link with `*`
Example - `http://localhost/photo_gallery/public/show_c.html/color-1*` The requested URL was not found on this server.
The others work's `color-3`, `wood`, etc.

1. generated map - `map.txt`

   ```
   title   id
   color-1* 1
   color-1** 2
   color-3 3
   wood 4
   color777 5
   color-test 6
   ```
2. htaccess

   ```
   RewriteRule ^show_c.html/([-\w]+)$ show_c.php?cat=${catcolors:$1} [L]
   ```
3. httpd.conf

   ```
   RewriteMap catcolors "txt:C:\wamp\www\photo_gallery\public\maps\map.txt"
   ```

My question. Why the link with `*` cannot be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^show_c.html/([-\w]+)$ show_c.php?cat=${catcolors:$1} [L]
> ```

The regex `[-\w]+` does not match `*`, so the pattern never matches the requested URL-path and the value is never looked up in the rewrite map.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteRule ^show_c\.html/([-*\w]+)$ show_c.php?cat=${catcolors:$1} [L]
```

The literal `*` does not need to be backslash escaped in the regex character class as it carries no special meaning here. (But remember to backslash escape literal dots in other parts of the regex.)

Specifically, the regex `[-*\w]+` matches 1 or more of the following:
`-` (hyphen), `*` (asterisk), `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and `_` (underscore)

Comment: I knew I had to add somewhere *.  Thank you very much again.

Comment: You're welcome. I've just updated my answer with what it does actually match.

Comment: live `http://mantykora.cleoni.com:8080/photo_gallery/public/show_c.html/color-1*` with this `RewriteRule ^show_c\.html/([-*\w]+)$ show_c.php?cat=${catcolors:$1} [L]`